# Why can't I set a data template inside a style, but I can inside a control template?

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate, controltemplate, setter

Why doesn't this work:

```
 <Style TargetType="s:Substance">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Name}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Count}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I switch to `ControlTemplate` it works, but I need a data template. Also, if I replace `Template` with `DataTemplate` it doesn't recognize the property. Does anyone know what is going on? Thank you.

NOTE: Substance derives from `FrameworkElement`. It is not a control.

Comment: @NestorArturo I updated the question, substance derives from `FrameworkElement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to know what you are doing, [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) expects a `ControlTemplate`, this property sets the template of the control itself, not its data.

Does your `Substance` control even have any property that expects a `DataTemplate`? e.g. [`ContentTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) (if it is a `ContentControl`) or [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) (if it is an `ItemsControl`)?

**Edit:** You probably just want to do this:

```
<Some.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Substance}"> <!-- The use of x:Type is important! -->
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Some.Resources>
```

Which defines a datatemplate for `Substance`; Wherever `Substance` is added as content or item, that datatemplate will be automatically applied.

Comment: Substance derives from FrameworkElement. What I would like to do is when I put it in a ComboList to have certain appearance like the name followed by a textbox. Should I set an item template instead? If I use an item template would the template only show when I add it to a control that expects items, in other words it won't show if I add it to a stack panel?

Comment: @mihajlv: Controls are not reactive like that, you usually don't define controls which behave in certain ways depending on where they are used. Usually you either associate a `DataTemplate` with its data-type (by adding it to a resource without setting the key), or you tell the control containing the data how it should show it using either the `Content`- or `ItemTemplate` properties.

Comment: @mihajlv: `FrameworkElement` does not deal with templating data, not quite sure what you expect this control to accomplish...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is not a control, it is just an object that I wan't to display, when added in a panel or in a ComboList. On a side note then if I derived from Control then I can set either ControlTemplate or DataTemplate

Comment: @mihajlv: Don't make date objects derive form controls, just declare a datatemplate for them in the resources!

Comment: Also, if just wanted to display an Object in a Panel or ListBox what is the most necessary class I need to derive from, noting that the object is not a control.

Comment: @mihajlv: Just declare a datatemplate, leave the object be! (see my edit)

Comment: @mihajlv: Another note, the `DataContext` in the `DataTemplate` is the object that is being templated, the data. The bindings should just be normal bindings to the properties on that data, `TemplateBinding` is for `ControlTemplates` only.

Comment: Thank you again, you said that the x:Type is important in your edit, why couldn't we just say s:Substance?

Comment: @mihajlv: Because `DataType` is on type `object`, so it would interpret that as a string, but you want it to be a type. See the reference of the property for more information, it's that way because of XML.